# How can we fill a salesForce lightning aura:attribute element with custom object?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I'm trying to fill `<aura:attribute name="selectedQuotation" type="salesTool.Quotation__c" />`  in any way that could works

Filling it with default value compile (means i can save the file)

```
default="{ 'sobjectType': 'salesTool__Quotation__c',
'Name': 'Test',
'Id':'',
'salesTool__Contact__c':'',
'salesTool__Package__c':'',
'salesTool__Signed__c':false,
'salesTool__Site__c':''
}"
```

But a "Uncaught Error: ComponentDef Config required for registration" Error is raised in browser logs at runtime.
The folloing demonstration example works well for me :

```
<aura:attribute name="newExpense" type="salesTool.Expense__c"
default="{ 'sobjectType': 'salesTool__Expense__c',
'Name': '',
'salesTool__Amount__c': 0,
'salesTool__Client__c': '',
'salesTool__Date__c': '',
'salesTool__Reimbursed__c': false
}"/>
```

But my case is different in a way i use lookupFields and not only literals.

Filling it with an instance of myCustomObject through application event result in an other error.
As it seems my aura:attribute is empty at the initialisation of the component, the variable **last**  in a aura source code is null and cause error.

```
 if (value.auraType === "Component" || !value.isLiteral()) {
            var last = component.lastRenderedValue;
            if (last !== value) {
                var referenceNode = **last**.getReferenceNode();
```

If somebody have some better experience of lightning, I would appreciate some help ;)

Comment: Hello, DemoMan, can you add some more details on the bigger picture of what you are trying to do with `last.getReferenceNode()`? Perhaps one of us can recommend an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a the value of a Lookup field with the Id of the record it references.

For example, if you have a Contact object you can specify a default for the Account lookup, by specifying an Id string for the AccountId field.

```
<aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Contact"
    default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact',
               'LastName': 'Smith',
               'AccountId': '001i000002zxpz1' 
             }"/>
```

You could also leave it blank and then set it in your JavaScript before calling to your Apex controller.

```
<aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Contact"
    default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact',
               'LastName': 'Smith',
               'AccountId': '' 
             }"/>
```

And, prior to enqueueing the action set the value explicitly.

```
var con = component.get("v.newContact");
con.AccountId = '001i000002zxpz1';
action.setParams({
    con: con
});
```

Or, you could leave it blank altogether and set it in your Apex controller:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Contact createContact(Contact con) {
    con.AccountId = '001i000002zxpz1';
    insert con;

    return con;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

DemoMan, you can set Lookup or Master-Detail field values in the exact same way you would set other sObject fields in Lightning, using `component.set()`. You can actually create a custom component, and pass the Lookup field as a value to it, in the following fashion:

```
<salesTool:inputLookupContact value="{!v.quote.salesTool__Contact__c}"/>
```

You can take a look at [this **oneContact.app demo**](https://github.com/martyychang/one-contact-tutorial) I created using a Contact object as the focal point, demonstrating how the `Contact.AccountId` field is manipulated using a custom `ccmt:inputLookupAccount` component.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys it seems my "Uncaught Error: ComponentDef Config required for registration"  was due to a silly error :

Writing this :

> {!v.selectedQuotation}

in a component leads to an error when you try to setup the "default" attibute of the aura:attribute element. whatever you set as attribute value.

> <aura:attribute name="selectedQuotation" type="salesTool.Quotation__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'salesTool__Quotation__c',...}" />

Changing the path {!v.selectedQuotation}  to a valid field like : {!v.selectedQuotation.Name} solved the issue